# Parallelization of Red Black SOR using OpenMb

Tags: performance, for-loop, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a square domain that I iterate over using Red-Black SOR solver. Because of the singularity on the centerline of the domain, I have to split each part (red and black) into three different zones (upper zone, lower zone, and centerline). I would like to know how I should parallelize the outer loops of red and black parts using openMP so that it would be the most efficient. Does it make sense to use #pragma omp parallel for also at inner loops?

Thanks.

```
     //****************************************Red nodes*************************************************

    //lower block
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int j =2; j<(vec[b].m+1)/2; ++j){
        for(int i =((j+1)%2)+2 ;i<vec[b].m; i+=2){      
            vec[b].node(i,j) =(1-omega)*vec[b].node(i,j)+ 0.25*omega* (vec[b].node(i+1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i-1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i, j-1)+
            vec[b].node(i, j+1)) - 
            h2* f[b].node(i ,j);       
        }
    }

    //center line
    int j =(vec[b].m+1)/2; 
        for(int i =((j+1)%2)+2 ;i<(vec[b].m+1)/2; i+=2){    
            vec[b].node(i,j) =(1-omega)*vec[b].node(i,j)+ 0.25*omega* (vec[b].node(i+1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i-1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i, j-1)+
            vec[b].node(i, j+1)) - 
            h2* f[b].node(i ,j);       
        }

    //upper block
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(j =(vec[b].m+1)/2+1; j<vec[b].m; ++j){
        for(int i =((j+1)%2)+2 ;i<vec[b].m; i+=2){  
            vec[b].node(i,j) =(1-omega)*vec[b].node(i,j)+ 0.25*omega* (vec[b].node(i+1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i-1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i, j-1)+
            vec[b].node(i, j+1)) - 
            h2* f[b].node(i ,j);       
        }
    }   


    //***************************************Black nodes*************************************************

    //lower block
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(j =2; j<(vec[b].m+1)/2; ++j){
        for(int i =((j%2)+2); i<vec[b].m; i+=2){        
            vec[b].node(i,j) =(1-omega)*vec[b].node(i,j)+ 0.25*omega* (vec[b].node(i+1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i-1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i, j-1)+
            vec[b].node(i, j+1)) - 
            h2* f[b].node(i ,j);       
        }
    }

    //middle line
        j =(vec[b].m+1)/2; 
        for(int i =((j%2)+2); i<(vec[b].m+1)/2; i+=2){  
            vec[b].node(i,j) =(1-omega)*vec[b].node(i,j)+ 0.25*omega* (vec[b].node(i+1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i-1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i, j-1)+
            vec[b].node(i, j+1)) - 
            h2* f[b].node(i ,j);       
        }

    //upper block
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(j =(vec[b].m+1)/2+1; j<vec[b].m; ++j){
        #pragma omp parallel for 
        for(int i =((j%2)+2); i<vec[b].m; i+=2){    
            vec[b].node(i,j) =(1-omega)*vec[b].node(i,j)+ 0.25*omega* (vec[b].node(i+1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i-1,j)+
            vec[b].node(i, j-1)+
            vec[b].node(i, j+1)) - 
            h2* f[b].node(i ,j);       
        }
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: how big is `vec[b].m` on avarage ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks for the comment. on the finest grid, it has 2^22 elements.

Comment: so the outer loop executes 2097151 iterations, I guess you have 4 or 8 threads, can you see any benefit in adding even more parallel execution flows ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That's exactly what I do not know precisely. I personally think I must only parallelize the outer loops.

Comment: if the number of parallel execution flows greately outnumbers the amount of threads, there's little chance you will gain anything by parallelizing inner loops. consider other optimization techniques like tiling

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The number of iterations of the inner loop decrease with each iteration of the outer loop. Therefore, you should set the scheduling of the outer loop to be `schedule(dynamic,something)` and experiment with different values of `something`.